# What are AWS S3 requests? How to separate them into external and internal S3 requests in billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-billing

Our S3 bill went haywire last month with a whopping 4.8 billion requests. I'm attaching a screenshot:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to know which S3 buckets these requests went to?
2. Where to learn about S3 requests and pricing in detail? This AWS Documentation has a very little info about this matter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/aws-usage-report-understand.html
3. In general, how to learn about the best practices using S3?

We have two buckets which we write data to and read data from. The major read we do is from a third external S3 bucket, which works on "requester-pays" basis. However, we have been doing several calculations for the past several days and we couldn't figure out where these 4.8 B requests came from.

Anyone has any idea about these questions?

Comment: See [S3 Storage Lens](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/new/2022/amazon-s3-storage-lens-increases-organization-wide-visibility-with-34-new-metrics/) which makes it "easier than ever to spot buckets with surprising access patterns".

Comment: S3 pricing is here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ (in general, you can Google for `foo pricing`, where "foo" is your AWS service, and get to the right page)

Comment: Are you running any analytics workloads against your buckets? That would be the most likely cause for large numbers of GET requests, outside of a DDOS attack. Especially if your data objects are small.

Comment: I also recommend Storage Lens - the data from that will inform you as to what the culprit is here.